# Image deleted regardless if checkbox is checked or not

Tags: wordpress, checkbox

I have a problem I'm trying to solve, but with no avail because php is really not my field. I already searched the forums and found a few solutions to similar problems, but I couldn't get the to work.

I created a Theme Options Page where you can for ex. upload a Logo to be used on the Website. I created a check box and want to delete the logo if the check box is checked. Anyway, the logo is deleted when I click Save changes, but regardless if I checked the check box or not.

This is my code:

```
// LOGO
function logo_setting() {
    $options = get_option('theme_options');
    if (empty($options['logo'])) :
        $options['logo'] = '';
    else :
        echo "<img src='{$options['logo']}' width='205px' /><br>";

        //DELETE OPTION
        if (!isset( $options['del_logo'] ) ) :
                $options['del_logo'] = '';
                echo "<br>Remove logo?&nbsp;";
                ?> <input type="checkbox" id="del_logo" name="theme_options[del_logo]" value="1" <?php checked( true, $options['del_logo'] ); ?> /><?php

                echo "<br>If logo is removed, Site Title will be used.";
            else :
                $options = get_option('theme_options');
                $options['logo'] = '';
                update_option('theme_options', $options);
                echo "Logo removed";
        endif;
        $options['del_logo'] = ( $options['del_logo'] == 1 ? 1 : 0 );
        return $options;

    endif;
    echo "<input type='file' name='logo' />";
}
```

I hope someone can explain to me what I'm doing wrong and how I should do it properly.

Comment: What hook are you running your function on?

Comment: `add_action('admin_menu', 'my_theme_menu');
function my_theme_menu() {
 add_menu_page('Theme Options', 'MY THEME Options', 'administrator', __FILE__, 'my_theme_options');
}`

Comment: and the settings are registered like:

`add_action('admin_init', 'register_settings');
function register_settings() {
 register_setting('theme_options', 'theme_options', 'validate_setting');
 add_settings_section('main_section', 'Main Settings', 'section_cb', __FILE__);
 
 add_settings_field('logo', 'Logo', 'logo_setting', __FILE__, 'main_section');
}`

Answer (score 1):

The OP wrote:

> SOLUTION:
>
> ```
> function logo_setting() {
>     $options = get_option('theme_options');
>     if (empty($options['logo'])) :
>     $options['logo'] = '';
>     echo "Site title is used.<br>";
>     else :
>     echo "<img src='{$options['logo']}' width='205px' /><br>";
>     endif;  
>     echo "<input type='file' name='logo' />";
>
>     if (empty($options['hide_logo'])) :
>     $options['hide_logo'] = '';
>     endif;
>     echo '<br><br>Show site title instead of logo?&nbsp;<input name="theme_options[hide_logo]" id="hide_logo" type="checkbox" value="1" ' . checked( 1, $options['hide_logo'], false ) . ' />';
> }
> ```
>
> In the html:
>
> ```
>  <?php if (empty($options['logo']) || isset($options['hide_logo'])) :
>     bloginfo('name');
> else : ?>
>     <img src="<?php echo $options['logo']; ?>" alt="Logo" />
> <?php endif; ?>
> ```

Comment: ([Answered in a question edit and converted to a community wiki](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267434/what-is-the-appropriate-action-when-the-answer-to-a-question-is-added-to-the-que).)